# VBA code to automatically copy a row and paste to another sheet based off one columns entry

Tags: excel, vba

First of all I am super new to VBA and coding in general, however, I am building an excel workbook to automatically transfer a row in a table based off a single cell in a row. when this happens I need it to copy only the values in the cells as I have several formulas. when the copy paste operation is done I need to delete the row and re-order everything to the top while not deleting the formulas of the row. below is what I have got so far which mostly works for what I need. the only issues are it copies the entire row so I cant have a merged group of cells to the right of the row and it deletes the formulas from the cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 8 Then
    If Target = "COMPLETED" Then


   Set Tbl = Sheets("PMI ARCHIVE").ListObjects("Table3")
     Tbl.ListRows.Add
     nxtTblRow = Tbl.ListColumns(9).Range.Rows.Count


    Target.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=Tbl.Range(nxtTblRow, 1)


    Application.EnableEvents = False
      Target.Row.ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End If
 End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: try this to clear the values and preserve the formulas: ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents. On the other hand I dont understand the second problem you have regording copying the entire row etc. Please try to explain better. I guess you can solve that handling the ranges you want to copy/paste/clear, handling that in the code itself

Comment: Do you want copying only the cells having formulas? In your code you paste all the row. If you want to paste only formulas, do you want to do that keeping their columns in the initial place?

Comment: the reordering is fine I have that worked out I simply need the copy paste function to copy only values from the first 9 columns in a given row. then paste them to a similar table on another sheet. also thank you for the help!

Comment: this command ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents I do not understand and it preserved my formulas but deleted everything else in the whole sheet. I need only the target row to have the values copied then pasted to the other sheet and only values of that same row to be deleted.

Comment: How to delete the row "not deleting the formulas of the row"? Do you mean to clear contents for cells without a formula?

Comment: Do you want sorting only column A:A?

Comment: arrCopy = Range(Target.Row, lastColT).Value   <-- that line produces error '1004' method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please. It assumes that you need to copy all existing values of the `Target` row and then clear contents of the cells not having a formula:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim arrCopy As Variant, lastColT As Long
  If Target.Column = 8 Then
        If Target = "COMPLETED" Then
             Set tbl = Sheets("PMI ARCHIVE").ListObjects("Table3")
             tbl.ListRows.aDD
             nxtTblRow = tbl.ListColumns(9).Range.Rows.Count

             lastColT = Cells(Target.row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
             arrCopy = Range(Target.row, lastColT).Value
             tbl.Range(nxtTblRow, 1).Resize(, UBound(arrCopy, 2)).Value = arrCopy

             Application.EnableEvents = False
                Range(Target.row, lastColT).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
             Application.EnableEvents = True
            'If in column A:A, an empty cell will exist (because of the above code), the range will be set up to that empty cell. 
            'The next way, goes to the last cell:
            Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), _
                                               Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

I am not sure you need to sort only A:A column, but I kept the code as it was, from this point of view...